# Change the Java version Eclipse is running under

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, virtual-machine

I want to run my Eclipse in a newer Java version (jdk 1.7) because of compatibility problems with the Window Builder Plugin

"Eclipse is running under 1.6, but this Java project has a 1.7 Java compliance level, so will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version."

So I suppose, I've to change the vm of Eclipse in the configurations.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
eclipse.home.location=file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers/
eclipse.launcher=C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers\eclipse.exe
eclipse.launcher.name=Eclipse
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
eclipse.startTime=1351770082498
eclipse.vm=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
eclipse.vmargs=-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
```

But I'm not realy familiar with all the statements, and my question is which ones do I've to change in order to run Eclipse with jdk 1.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the [`eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/%C2%A0eclipse.ini) file to point `-vm` to `JDK 7`

Comment: openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll [guess its this file]
-vmargs [already in the file] Result: Eclipse: Failed to load JNI shared library.

Comment: I think it's because of the match 32 bit Eclipse vs 64 bit JDK, although I programmed java projects with a jre 7 64 bit without problems.

Comment: you need to be on 64 bit JDK and eclipse to take full advantage of your system. Point the -vm to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: You mean 64 bit JDK and 64 bit Eclipse? I want to proceed with my 32 bit Eclipse. Result of javaw.exe: Exit code 13. I'm now downloading the 32 bit jdk.